# Сохранение данных в Android (API level 7)

Tags: android, java

Добрый день,

Сам я в java ни разу ни опытен, думаю вы меня просвятите лучше.
Есть код под android 2.1, хочу из одной функции сохранить определенные данные (короткие текстовые файлики). Крайне желательно сохранять не в internal, а на флешку. 
Проще всего конечно лить в корень, но я приверженец отрывания рук за такое. Поэтому вопрос, как определить куда писать?

Склоняюсь к определению пути вот таким образом (но напрягает hard кодинг:))

```
private String appPrivateDir = Environment.getDataDirectory().toString()+"/data/"+getClass().getPackage().getName().toString()+"/files";
```

еще думал вот над таким

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath().toString();
```

но оно лаконично выводит лишь /sdcard , что тоже не очень устраивает ))

p.s. и второй отвлеченный вопрос, с помощью sharedPreferences можно сохраняться многострочные значения? getString() маловато будет..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все гораздо проще:

```
File previewDir = new File(getExternalFilesDir(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath());
```

В результате при выполнении

```
previewDir.mkdir();
```

на SD-карте создастся иерархия вида:
`/Android/data/your_package_name/files/downloads/`,
где `your_package_name` - имя пакета приложения, заданное в манифесте.
И далее, можно уже ложить файлы сюда. Есть в классе Environment и другие константы. А еще была статья на Хабре про это. Поищите, будет полезно.

Еще добавлю:

1. Это рекомендуемый способ хранения файлов(в папке /Android и далее)
2. При удалении приложения удаляться и эти данные, что очень важно. Пользователю не нужно будет постоянно ручками удалять данные с карты и кричать матом на ваше приложение

**UPD2**

На счет SharedPreferences. Что мешает сохранить строку с символами перевода на новую строку - "\n"? Попробуйте, должно работать. В любом случае, SharedPreferences - это просто XML-ка, лежащая внутри директории с приложением.

Comment: Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS is first available in API 2.2

Comment: Делаете в манифесте или в свойстве проекта - targetSDK = 2.3.3, minSDK = 2.1 и у вас все будет хорошо. В чем проблема? Сейчас больше всего девайсов под версией 2.3.х. А вы заявляете о 2.2.

Comment: хочу поглядеть что за путь будет, а оно валиться в exeption.. Что я делаю не так?

    String previewDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath();
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),previewDir, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();

Comment: У меня есть подозрение что из-за вывода getApplicationContext(). Не стоит его вызывать не зная зачем он. Контекст, говоря простым языком - это текущий активити, потому правильнее писать так:
Toast.makeText(CurrentActivity.this,previewDir, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
А вообще, для получения ответа пишите еще и какой эксепшн валится.

Comment: 04-25 16:40:52.581: E/AndroidRuntime(280): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

А так работает..

    String previewDir = "Hello";
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),previewDir,     Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();

Comment: Ну так у вас в targetSDK стоит до сих пор версия 2.1, потому и не работает. Ибо нет такого метода.

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>

Comment: Все равно падает? Тогда создайте папку, как я выше написал, пробуйте еще и вызывайте код получения пути внутри активити. Да и вообще, все что выше внутри активити должно быть.

Answer (score 0):

Я решаю это так:

Переопределяю в своем активити метод `Context.getExternalFilesDir()` (без переопределения он все равно будет ссылаться на `Environment.getExternalFilesDir()`).

После переопределения он у меня смотрит на что-то вроде **/sdcard/mydir** - естественно в ходе переопределения можно устроить проверку наличия каталога, смонтирована ли карта и проч.

Comment: И зачем это делать? Велосипед чистой воды получается. Используете готовые методы для готового функционала. И кроме того теряете удобство очистки при удалении приложения.